# - ddms] transfer error: open failed：Permission denied

Tags: android

I get a trouble when learning android Data-Persistence.
I changed the da[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cChqZ.png)ta/data/com.flexible.filepersistencetest/files/data  permission  to 777. But I still can't pull it to my PC.

when I try to delete Nexus_5_API_24.avd  's permission of Read-Only, the Read-Only  will be back.
It really exaust me.
Any advice is ok, thank you very much!

Comment: I have solved it. It is because that I haven't have the root of my emulator.

Answer (score 1):

1. change file permissions.

   [image: snapshot terminal]

   ```
   C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools> adb shell 
   generic_x86:/ $ su
   generic_x86_64:/ # chmod -R 777 /data 
   generic_x86_64:/ # exit
   ```
2. run the below commands under the terminal in Android studio integration.

   ```
   C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools> adb shell 
   generic_x86:/ $ 
   generic_x86:/ $ exit 
   $ adb root 
   restarting adbd as root
   $ adb shell 
   generic_x86:/ # exit
   ```
3. open cmd windows.

   ```
   C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools> adb pull /data/data/xxxx C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools
   ```

   or use "pull" button 
   [image: button bull]